# No puedo ingresar un valor por consola

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo una aplicación muy sencilla, en el cual pido ingresar un valor.
cuando ejecuto el programa, corre sin errores, pero cuando tipeo el valor y lo ingreso el programa no reacciona, me explico?

```
contador=0 #email=False

miemail=input("introduce un Email: ")
for i in miemail:
    if(i=="@" or i=="."):
        contador=contador+1#email==True
if contador==2: #email==True:
    print("Email es correcto")
else:
    print("Email es incorreto")
```

en consola:
introduce un Email:

pero cuando introduzco cualquier cosa y le doy enter no hace absolutamente nada

Comment: Edita y agrega tu código por favor, de otro modo es imposible saber lo que esta mal

Comment: Hola Alejandro, bienvenido a [es.so]. Dado que `input` se limita a leer de stdin y retornar una cadena con lo obtenido, la "reacción" a lo que ingreses depende de lo que hagas con su retorno en tu código. Si no muestras el código y explicas (si no es fácilmente deducible ) lo que quieres que tu programa haga es completamente imposible saber que está mal  como comenta Aprendiz. Usa el link [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/283421/edit) que hay debajo de la pregunta y añade tu código o al menos un [mcve]. Te recomiendo también pasarte por [tour] y [ask]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar con una función.

```
def miemail(mail):
  miemail=mail
  arroba = miemail.count("@")
  punto = miemail.count(".")
  if (arroba==1 and punto==1):
      print("Email es correcto")
  else:
      print("Email es incorreto")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]